# How to get only the first letter of the first 2 words of a long string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a long string name. Example: `"Ahmet Enes Söylemez"`. I want to get only `"AE"` letters from this array. How can I do it ?

```
@{ string result = string.Concat(kullanici.AdSoyad.Where(char.IsUpper));
@result
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there: Just `.Take(2)`

```
string result = string.Concat(kullanici.AdSoyad.Where(char.IsUpper).Take(2));
```

Comment: Side note: technically the query returns first two upper case letters, there are no words in the query

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using *Regular Expressions* here and *match* these two words. If we assume that the word of interes must start from capital letter and must continue with low case leters we can implement it it like this:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string text = "Ahmet Enes Söylemez";

string letters = string.Concat(Regex 
  .Matches(text, @"\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+") // match each word of interest
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Take(2)       // We want just two first matches
  .Select(match => match.Value[0])); // Initial letters from each match
```

Here we use `\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+` which is

```
\p{Lu}  - capital letter
\p{Ll}+ - followed by one or more low case letters
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VNVDiq)